# Read numbers from txt and sort them - cast error

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to take numbers in the txt file which has white space between numbers and make in a sort list.
But I got the

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'. error

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Dosyası(*.txt)|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
{
    if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
        List<Double> list = new List<Double>();

        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            //int nmbr = 0;
            lines = s.Split(new char[] { }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            list.Add(Convert.ToDouble(lines));
            listfile.Items.Add((Convert.ToDouble(lines)));

        }

        list.Sort();
        foreach (Double x in list)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(x);
        }
```

Comment: You can't convert a list of strings to a double. Project each element with Select()  anche convert it, add with AddRange() .

Comment: can you give me more sample or edit it in my code

Comment: @SilasHayri - Can you please provide a sample of your input in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are reassigning your `lines` variable inside `foreach` statement which is incorrect.

Secondly, you are trying to convert an array of values instead of converting each of the value themselves.

```
foreach (string s in lines)
{
    //int nmbr = 0;
    var numbers = s.Split(new char[] { }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach(var number in numbers)
    {
        var convertedNumber = Convert.ToDouble(number);
        list.Add(convertedNumber);
        listfile.Items.Add(convertedNumber);
    }
 }
```

To order retrieved values in descending order you can do:

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

Once you have a sorted list, you can populate your listbox

```
foreach (Double x in list)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(x);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) I want to make the number in a order that the big number comes first and so on to the smallest number

Comment: But it doesnt order the number :(

Comment: What about this line? `list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();`

Comment: nope still just show the number in the txt file on both listbox

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<double>' to  System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
List<double> list =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(' '))
        .Select(double.Parse)
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .ToList();

foreach (double x in list)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(x);
}
```